# When storing long value in mongodb from java program the value is stored in this format NumberLong(n)

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

When storing long value from java program in `mongodb` the value is stored in this format

```
`NumberLong(n)`.

 db.mycollection.find()

    { "_id" : ObjectId("52bd9475c8ceae448b16c077"), "companyId" : NumberLong(10132), "tableId" : NumberLong(87803), "rowId" : NumberLong(88154), "classNameId" : NumberLong(10129), "classPK" : NumberLong(88153) }
```

but i want to store the values as 10132, 87803 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript only has a single numeric type `Number` which is stored as a double-precision floating point value.  The [`BSON` storage format](http://bsonspec.org/) used by MongoDB supports more native types than JavaScript, including 32-bit and 64-bit integers.

The `NumberLong()` value you see in the `mongo` shell is a the result of a helper function that represents 64-bit integers in JavaScript -- this confirms your numbers are being saved as expected.  If you read the values back via your Java program you will see they are still longs.

For more information see [Data Types in the `mongo` Shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/).